# In Nokogiri, how do I find all the nodes that come before a certain node in my document?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5, Ruby 2.4.  If I have located a node using Nokogiri parsing, how would I find all the nodes that occur before my found node that do not also include that found node?  That is, let's say my document is

```
<outer>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <inner>
        <most_inner class="abc">Howdy</most_inner>
        <most_inner class="def">Next</most_inner>
    </inner>
</outer>
```

and I run a query like

```
node = doc.search('//*[contains(@class, "def")]').first
```

How would I locate all the preceding nodes (that don't include the one I just identified)?  The nodes I would expect would be

```
<p>Hello</p>
<most_inner>Howdy</most_inner>
```

Comment: Why isn't `<inner>` selected? Why are you locating the last `<most_inner>` node? Do you only want the immediate preceding sibling for `<inner>` or all others at that level? Your question doesn't show evidence of much effort. Please read "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" and "[mcve]".

Comment: inner includes the most_inner node, he wants to exclude that as well as I understood it

Comment: Hi @TheChamp, you are correct -- whatever the node in question is, I wish to find all preceding nodes that do not also contain that node.

Comment: If `.abc` was actually `<really_inner class="abc"><most_inner>Howdy</most_inner></really_inner>`, what do you expect in the answer? `most_inner`, `really_inner`, or both?

Comment: Is the entire document '<really_inner class="abc"><most_inner>Howdy</most_inner></really_inner>' in your example?  If so there are no nodes that come before the node with class "abc", so I would expect teh answer to be nothing.  If the document were "<a>Stuff<b>hi</b></a><really_inner class="abc"><most_inner>Howdy</most_inner></really_inner>", and dthe node in question were the one with class "abc", I woudl expect the answer to be "<a>Stuff<b>hi</b></a>"

Answer (score 5):

You just need to iterate over the leaf nodes until you reach the target node.

```
# Node to exclude
node = doc.search('//*[contains(@class, "def")]').first
preceding_nodes = []

# Find all leaf nodes
leaf_nodes = doc.xpath("//*[not(child::*)]")

leaf_nodes.each do |leaf|
  if leaf == node
    break
  else
    preceding_nodes.push(leaf)
  end
end

preceding_nodes # => Contains all preceding leaf nodes
```

Comment: I was just using a node with class="def" as an example -- the node in question may not have a class="def".  But your example wouldn't work anyway, right -- because it would pick out leaf nodes that occur after the node with class="def"?  I know my example doesn't have any such nodes, but another document might.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Wasn't quite clear about what you wanted. I've updated the answer accordingly!

Comment: Hi, I"m still not getting the desired results.  If I create a doc using " doc = Nokogiri.XML('<foo><a /><b class="def" /><c /><foo>', nil, 'EUC-JP') ", running your code returns the "<c />" node, which I don't want becuase it occurs after the node I'm looking at.  I only want to return nodes that precede (are before) the one in quesiton.

Comment: I misunderstood a second time! You just need to loop over node set until you reach your target node. Answer is updated.

Comment: I appreciate your reifning your answer.  THe problem is for some reason you are only considering leaf nodes.  That is not a requirement of mine.  I want to find all nodes before my node in question that don't also contain that node.  So, this document, 'doc = Nokogiri.XML('<foo><a>This is <b>Bold</b> text</a><b class="def" /><c /><foo>', nil, 'EUC-JP')' doesn't include the "<a>" element using your logic -- probably because the "<a>" node has a "<b>" within it.